# render a Excel formula so you not longer need the other columns?

Tags: excel

Is it possible to get Excel to render the results of a formula so I can delete the extra columns that the data was derived from?

I am concatenating a few columns and once I have my final column with the final values I want I want to kill the old ones.

Comment: The only way to get excel to delete columns automatically is through VBA. I assume it's more than a one-time thing, otherwise you can just delete manually.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you really are sure you don't need the old data anymore, you can just copy the whole result column, select `Paste Special->Paste as Values`.

You'll lose the formula, but your column will just be replaced with the result of the formula calculation.

However it would probably be a better practice just to hide the old columns though, you're going to regret it if you erase all your source data and then find a slight formula error or typo.